# Optional where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table

Table A - Product information - color, size etc...(product_id, color, size...)

Table B - Rate information - rate might vary by color, size, state etc...
(rate_id, product_id, color, size, state, rate)

Not all products have rates that vary by color, size, state etc...This changes by product

If that is the case only attributes by which rates vary have a value in the rate table
e.g. if Product X rate does not vary by size or state but varies by color there will entries in the rate table with different color values but the size, state field will be null.

Is there a way in SQL to get the right rate value for a product
- I cannot match on all product attributes because there might not be a matching row

What I want is a query that gets the rate associated with Product X and will work with for other products whose rates may vary by different set of attributes.

Comment: You would do best, I think, to make the schema simpler.  Table A should not contain the color or size information.  Table B should always contain one or more rows for a given product_id.  You always do an INNER join between the tables.  No need for conditionality.

Comment: Agreed that the schema is definitely "off".  If the number of rows are small and the tables aren't used everywhere, fixing the table structure is a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you want to know about the subject, and more: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would implement it

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-a-dynamic-where-clause

And a very good explaination here
http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with static SQL with the trick `ISNULL(product.color, 'n/a') = ISNULL(rate.color, ISNULL(product.color, 'n/a'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an outer join?

```
SELECT
   P.*,
   R.*
FROM 
   PRODUCT P LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE R 
   ON (P.product_ID = R.product_id AND (
       P.COLOR = R.COLOR
    OR P.SIZE  = R.SIZE
   ))
WHERE
   P.product_id = ?
```

Edit:  Left off the WHERE clause.